# need help getting terminal and getting a browser

Tags: command-line, dual-boot, software-center, browser, chromebook

I just downloaded unity to my chromebook and I only have uxterm and xterm but I don't have the regular terminal and it wont let me download software center in either uxterm or xterm so I need help getting terminal, software center and a browser. I have look at many videos on youtube already and tried all the steps in the video but none of them worked. Help would be appreciated thank you. Also when ever I try apt-get update or upgrade it says premission denied and are you root?

Answer (score 2):

Your on xterm and cannot download software center which is a GUI app and your on console.. 
I suggest you use apt-get to install software and you begin with installing ubuntu-desktop and then you can install your browsers and related.. there is one browser you could use called elinks

to install Ubuntu desktop

```
 sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

or install gnome desktop

```
 sudo apt-get install gnome-desktop-environment
```

then install your software center or use apt-get. To install the commandline browser

```
 sudo apt-get install elinks
```

and browse like this

```
 elinks www.google.com #opens Google
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To install packages with apt-get, you must have root privileges. The easiest way to do that is to type `sudo` in front of the commands which require root privileges. For example, to install *gnome-terminal*, the command would be `sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal`; you will then need to type your password before the command runs. You should use `sudo` for the update and upgrade commands as well, since they all require root privileges.

To install any package, you should use the command `sudo apt-get install <package-name>`, replacing `<package-name>` by the actual name of the package you wish to install. Here are some packages you might be interested in installing:

Terminal: `gnome-terminal`

Web browser: `firefox`, `chromium-browser` (note: this is Chromium, not Google Chrome, although it is similar)

Ubuntu Software Center: `software-center`

Answer (score 0):

Press `ctrl+alt+T` to open Terminal and after doing so try the below command,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install tor-browser
```